# Google App Engine: Trouble with Datastore Query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This query works:

```
item = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Item WHERE CSIN = 13")[0]
```

although if there are no results returned, it blows up in my face. (How can I get around this? A `for` loop seems dubious when I want at max one iteration.)

This query does not work:

```
item = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Item WHERE CSIN = :1", CSIN)[0]
```

`CSIN` is a string representing a number. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 507, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "path\to\src\Main.py", line 42, in get
    item = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Item WHERE CSIN = :1", CSIN)[0]
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 1717, in __getitem__
    raise IndexError('The query returned fewer than %d results' % (arg+1))
IndexError: The query returned fewer than 1 results
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to get an item from a list (or a list-like object) that is empty.  What you're doing is sort of comparable to the following:

```
>>> results = [] # an empty list
>>> item = results[0] # Raises an IndexError, because there is nothing in the list
```

What you need to do instead is:

```
item = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Item WHERE CSIN = :1", CSIN).get()
```

Then, `item` will be either `None` or the first result from the query.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that that your query returns an array or list of some sort, which is empty. Trying to access its non-existing first item raises an exception.

Try to figure out the length of the returned result before accessing it.

Comment: How can I figure out its length?

Comment: As Will points out in the other answer, you need to use get() or fetch(n) to actually get results from the query.